# С++ ошибка при использовании шаблонов класса

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Пишу на С++ в `Visual Studio 2019` и практикуюсь с шаблонами классов.
Написал код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


template <class Name, class Pointer>
class PropertyDescriptor {
    public:
        Name name;
        Pointer* pointer;

        PropertyDescriptor(Name name, Pointer* pointer) {
            this->name = name;
            this->pointer = pointer;
        }
};

int main() {
    int b;
    string c = "string";
    PropertyDescriptor <string, int*> descriptor(c, &b);

    return 0;
}
```

Но выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

IDE говорит что `std::string, int *` и `std::string, int *` не совпадают? Что вызывает ошибку (ведь вроде все правильно)? И в чём ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И что вы ему говорите?

```
PropertyDescriptor <string, int*> descriptor(c, &b);
```

Т.е. ваш тип `Pointer` у вас - `int*`.

Значит,

```
Pointer* pointer;
```

превращается в

```
int ** pointer;
```

И передавать вы в конструктор

```
PropertyDescriptor(Name name, Pointer* pointer)
```

должны не `int*`, как передаете, а `int**`.

Вы сами себя сбили тем, что дали обычному типу название `Pointer`... Иногда (и часто!) имя имеет значение :)

Вот так оно логичнее:

```
template <class Name, class Pointer>
class PropertyDescriptor {
    public:
        Name name;
        Pointer pointer;

        PropertyDescriptor(Name name, Pointer pointer) {
            this->name = name;
            this->pointer = pointer;
        }
};
```

И, кстати, в последних стандартах - C++17 - компилятор уже умеет сам выводить параметры типа из переданных аргументов, так что код

```
template <class Name, class Pointer>
class PropertyDescriptor {
    public:
        Name name;
        Pointer* pointer;

        PropertyDescriptor(Name name, Pointer* pointer) {
            this->name = name;
            this->pointer = pointer;
        }
};

int main() {
    int b;
    string c = "string";
    PropertyDescriptor descriptor(c, &b);

    return 0;
}
```

компилируется без замечаний и ошибок.

Comment: Иногда (и часто!) имя имеет значение .  Я бы сказал огромное значение...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну, понимаете, начинающие программисты всегда подразумевают - "для компилятора" :)

Comment: Хмм... я с самого начала понел так как нужно: Страуструп жирными буквами отмечает, что не нужно деревом называть автомобиль... (простая логика)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вас я бы не назвал начинающим :)

Comment: Но я был им когда то... И  вы тоже

Comment: Спасибо что ответ с объяснением и вполне исчерпывающим. Но есть одно но, у меня Visual Studio почему-то ругается на отсутвие аргументов шаблона класса.

Comment: Вы немного ошиблись :) предположив, что в конструктор я хотел передавать сам `int` а не указатель на него. Идея заключалась в том, что параметр с типом `Pointer` - это указатель на любой тип данных (в данном случае - `int`).

Comment: Я не ошибся. Если вы немного подумаете, то поймете, что мой вариант и есть - передача в конструктор указателя. Что до VC++ - укажите стандарт c++17 в настройках.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> PropertyDescriptor <string, int*> descriptor(c, &b);
> ```

```
PropertyDescriptor <string, int> descriptor(c, &b);
```

Comment: но я же ссылку передаю

Comment: неправда <7символов>

Comment: @Евгений Бабийчук: Где у вас в коде ссылка???